# Could not find subkey System\CurrentControlSet\Services\MSSQLFDLauncher$INSTANCE_NAME

Tags: sql-server, clustering

I am getting the following error when attempting to add a node to an existing SQL Server 2016 Clustered instance on a Windows 2012 R2 Server

> ### TITLE: SQL Server Setup failure.
>
> SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:
>
> Could not find subkey
>   System\CurrentControlSet\Services\MSSQLFDLauncher$INSTANCE_NAME
>
> Error code 0x851B0001.
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&EvtType=0x121D5FF7%25400x24ECD2CC%25401307%25401

Has anyone encountered this error and/or found a way to get around it?

I have done the following in an attempt to resolve:

1. Rebooted
2. Added the missing key to the registry

There are other instances that I have successfully added to this same machine. So there is no rational reason why this instance can't be added as well.

Thanks,

P.S. The link provided in the error goes to a page about the Surface Laptop.

**Update 06/23/2017**

**More information:**

- This is a clustered instance with SQL Server Analysis Services that
  is also clusterized.
- The add node is using software with SP1 slipstreamed in
  ProductUpdates
- The error occurs when I get to the Perform Volume Maintenance screen
  which adds the SQL Server service user to that role.

Comment: What account are you running the installer as?  Does it have sufficient permissions on the server (e.g. part of the local Administrators group)?

Comment: @JohnEisbrener, running as user with administrative rights on the server.

Comment: This is likely a permissions issue, so the next step is to see if someone with elevated rights on **both** the server **and** the domain can run it without issue.  Sometimes the installer will fail when [creating objects on the domain](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2013/09/30/error-during-installation-of-an-sql-server-failover-cluster-instance/).  This generally results in a different error, so I don't think this is your issue, but I've seen the installer throw red herrings before, and this would at least eliminate the permissions issue as being the root cause.